# How to backup the blockchain file?

Tags: blockchain, lmdb

How can I periodically backup the blockchain file, without copying the entire file (just the new data that was added since the last backup)?

I tried copying only the amount of bytes by which the blockchain is larger than the backup ("filling the gap"), but that didn't seem to work - the daemon failed to load the blockchain from this backup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

rsync copies what's changed:

rsync ~/.bitmonero/lmdb/data.mdb /mnt/wherever/monero-blockchain/data.mdb

This should be done when nothing is writing to the blockchain database file. If you need to copy while it is being written to, use mdb_copy:

mdb_copy ~/.bitmonero/lmdb /mnt/wherever/monero-blockchain/

Note how mdb_copy wants the directory, and not the file.

Comment: The simplest solution I could ask for!

Comment: Using rsync or mdb_copy like this will copy the whole database file. Not just what's changed.

Comment: This is not a solution.

Comment: If it copies everything as is, edit the post to add appropriate rsync options, or add an answer with those.