# How can I back up my node efficiently?

Tags: full-node, backup

I have two external disks, each with a copy of the Monero blockchain. Most of the time, one of the disks sits in a cupboard and its copy of the blockchain lags behind. Every few days, I plug it in and restart *monerod* with a suitable argument to `--data-dir`.

My internet connection is slow, so the efficient way to synchronize my lagging copy against my synchronized copy would surely be **something purely local**. Perhaps I could run two instances of *monerod* on the same machine, with settings that cause one of my disks to synchronize against the other; but I don't know what command-line arguments to use. Can someone provide an example?

Or, if there's a better way, what is it? For instance, are there generic computer backup protocols that can update the lagging file by reference to the up-to-date file?

***Edit:*** [user36303](https://monero.stackexchange.com/users/22/user36303) has previously provided [*two* good answers](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6210/how-to-backup-the-blockchain-file) to this question. I'm accepting [jtgrassie](https://monero.stackexchange.com/users/7493/jtgrassie)'s answer (below) though, because it works using *monerod* itself, *i.e.* with no requirement to install anything else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to backup the blockchain file?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6210/how-to-backup-the-blockchain-file)

Comment: The downside with that answer is it requires a full copy vs just syncing/copying new blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Perhaps I could run two instances of monerod on the same machine, with settings that cause one of my disks to synchronize against the other; but I don't know what command-line arguments to use. Can someone provide an example?

If you start a second `monerod` instance like:

```
monerod --p2p-bind-port 38080 --rpc-bind-port 38081 --zmq-rpc-bind-port 38082 \
    --no-igd --hide-my-port --p2p-bind-ip 127.0.0.1 \
    --data-dir /path/to/backup/data \
    --add-exclusive-node 127.0.0.1:18080
```

It will sync it's blockchain from your main, localhost, instance of `monerod`.