# How to back up only new blocks on blockchain using rsync

Tags: monerod, blockchain, lmdb, backup

Using rsync in the normal way copies the entire blockchain to backup every time new blocks are added. To get around this, I used the --append flag, however even though the size of the backup is the same as the newly updated blockchain, if I run monerod connected to the backup, it does not show the backed up blockchain as synced. So, is there a way to back up my blockchain ***incrementally*** in a way that the backed up blockchain will be usable and correctly synced?

[This post](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6210/how-to-backup-the-blockchain-file) does not give a correct answer as that simply copies over the whole blockchain every time that rsync command is run, which does not help at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two included tools that can help here: `monero-blockchain-export` and  `monero-blockchain-import`.

If you backup (i.e. export) to a *bootstrap* file (a .raw file, the default), it keeps track of its current height and thus subsequent exports will simply *append* to the output file.

Upon restoration (i.e. import), if your database already exists, the default is to *resume* importing from the current height.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, what I should do is continue to backup how I am doing, and when I need to use the backed up chain, I need to use the monero-blockchain-import tool in order for sync to pick up at the last block added?

Comment: Yes. That said, backing up the blockchain is a moot point - it's already "backed up" on every other Monero users node.

Comment: Ok great. The reason I back it up is because if I lose my copy, it's a very long process to re-download again. It's a time saver backup.